# Static Html page is not working after hosting in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

In my MVC project, There is a `Default.html` file in root folder and route this file as a default route.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "",
            url: "Default.html"
            //,
            //defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

It's working fine when I access it like `http://localhost:51353/Default.html`

I host (include this static file) this project in my web server. But it's showing error:

[image: 404 Error]

Is there any additional configuration needed to do this ?

Comment: check `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` in webconfig. Since it is working in localhost this can be one issue, its solved mine

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to host a `static HTML page` within an `ASP.net MVC` project then you need to configure your routing configuration in `MVC` to ignore requests for those pages.

It worked locally because you may have set it as start page in Visual Studio. For this to work you need to tell `MVC` to ignore the route if its for the `HTML page` or `ASPX page`. Find your routing configuration section, it’s in `RouteConfig.cs` under the `App_Start` folder. Use the `IgnoreRoute()` method to tell Routing to ignore the specific paths.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Default.html"); //ignore the specific HTML page
```

Now `MVC` ignores a request to load the `Default.html` page and leaves `IIS` to handle the resource.

Answer (score 0):

As per the MVC Routing you cannot map static files to the routing table, because when MVC Routing Machanism provides direct access to physically exist static files.